# kill next expression in paredit

Tags: emacs, clojure, lisp, paredit

In emacs paredit-mode one can kill all following expressions which are inside the current line by hitting `Ctrl+k`:

```
(1 |(2 3) 4 5)
(1)
```

How can you do the same thing, but just affecting the next expression:

```
(1 |(2 3) 4 5)
(1 4 5)
```

Answer (score 6):

try C-M-k (ctrl+alt+k)
It is not the paredit feature, but emacs native editing feature:

http://www.cliki.net/Editing+Lisp+Code+with+Emacs